# I'm trying to convert int to BigInteger can someone help me?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that converts values to bits.  Everything worked well till I got to GB(gigabytes).  So for instance 1 GB should equal 8 billion bits but the result is giving me a negative answer.  Here is my code can someone give me some insight?

```
else if(line.equals("GB")) {
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many GigaBytes are you transfering to bits?");
        int number = num.nextInt();
        //int ans = number * 8 * 1000000000;
        BigInteger bigAns = BigInteger.valueOf(number * 8 * 1000000000);
        System.out.println(number + " GigaByte(s) equals " + bigAns + " bits.");
    }
```

Here is the output I'm getting: 1 GigaByte(s) equals -589934592 bits.

Comment: Guess what an int times 2 other ints results in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't be a bad thing to use `BigInteger` throughout your calculations.  This way, you don't run the risk of overflow while multiplying these numbers.

```
BigInteger bigAns = BigInteger.valueOf(number).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(8))
                              .multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(1000000000L));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a negative number because you are exceeding the maximum possible value for a signed 32bit integer and causing an overflow.

When dealing with large numbers like this, you should use `long` instead, which is capable of holding much larger numbers.

To implement this, change `int ans = number * 8 * 1000000000` to`long ans = number * 8 * 1000000000l`

Comment: Yes it's true. And if rather than writing 8 * 1000000000, you write 8000000000, you will see your compiler rejecting your number.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you get is a garbage value.
You can convert int to BigInteger by doing so:

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(myInteger.intValue());
```

And as Bohsulav said:

You can use this number * 8 * 1000000000l to prevent the overflow.

*Helped? Let me know :)*

Answer (score 0):

First convert to biginteger *then* perform the computations.

```
BigInteger.valueOf(number * 8 * 1000000000);
```

Here, you perform the computation in int, then convert to BigInteger *afterwards, when it is too late*.

Use BigInteger.valueOf(number), then call appropriate methods to perform your computation.